# references as superscript in square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

How do I put the references as superscript in square brackets using `revtex4`?
Tried to use

```
\usepackage [super]{cite}
\citeleft
\citeright
```

but this package cannot be used with `revtex.`

I am using `\begin{thebibliography}` with `\bibitem{}` for the references.

Here the MWE (transferred from a comment by the OP: by C.Hupfer)

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} % accept eps files for pdflatex compiler
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in} 
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}

\graphicspath{{figures//}} 
\begin{document} 
    \title{title} 
\begin{abstract} 
   text 
\end{abstract} 
\maketitle Citation example \cite{one}. 
\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
   \bibitem{one} Name Surname, Phys. Rev. B {\bf 1}, 1 (2001). 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does `reftex4` publishers allow for such superscript references? ;-)

Comment: If I use prb style with revtex I can use superscript references, but I can find no way t use square brackets with them.

Comment: Please add code to the editor window, not as a comment ;-) I put it there, as an exception from my usual editings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `revtex4` document class loads the `natbib` citation management package, which is not compatible with the `cite` package.

The `revtex4` document class modifies natbib's `\NAT@citesuper` macro; it is this macro that needs to be modified to achieve your objective. I suggest doing so by loading the `etoolbox` package and using that package's `\patchcmd` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@citesuper}%
   {\textsuperscript{#1}}{\textsuperscript{[#1]}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

Citation example \cite{one}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{99} 
   \bibitem{one} Name Surname, Phys.~Rev.~B {\bfseries 1}, 1 (2001). 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```